# Decode pages line by line in PHP?

Tags: php, decode, fopen

I would like to check if every word in a text file exists in any "LINES" of another large dictionary text file.

Every way I have tried this has failed, or worked only briefly.

How can I do without a million nested loops?

Comment: How big is the text file, how many words?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Do you really want to know if *every* word in the text file is in the dictionary (the answer would be a single 'yes' or 'no'), or do you want to know of every word in the text file if it is in the dictionary? (where you'd have as many answers as there are words in the text file). Also, "LINES" seems to imply something you're not being clear about. Do you mean that every word in the dictionary file is on its own line, or something else?

Comment: I like Will0's comment. Very semantically correct. And a good question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering this way too often. But a regex would avoid much of the looping.

```
// get words
preg_match_all(':\p{L}{2,}:u', $text_file, $words);
$words = end($words);

// make a search regex  "abc|foobar|xyz|text|.."
$rx_words = implode("|", $words);

// find all words that exist on a line
preg_match_all(':^($rx_words)$:', file_get_contents("LINES"), $cmp);

// everything found if:
$found_all = !array_diff($cmp[1], $words);
```

Reading in the whole `LINES` file can be avoided with some extra coding. But I wanted to keep it simple here.

Comment: Do you have a sense of when $words would get too big for this?

Comment: No idea. PCRE does optimize such group expressions I believe. It will certainly not run out of memory just because it's more than 1000 words. And I'm somewhat certain *PCRE* is faster than two PHP loops to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Psuedocode If you have enough memory:

```
for each line in text file:
   break line into words
   for each word in line:
       $wordMap[lowercase($word)] = 1;

for each line:
   break line into words
   for each word:
       if $wordMap[lowercase($word)] == 1:
          line has word $word
```

If you don't have enough memory for $wordMap, then make $wordMap some sort of database.  You might also try a bloom filter (http://code.google.com/p/php-bloom-filter/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).